# Volvo V70 touch screen no longer responding to touches

Tags: volvo, dashboard, entertainment-system

My V70 has a "Sensus Connected Touch" display, where most functions (radio, climate, settings menu, etc.) are displayed; some of these are operated via a menu dial and/or other, physical, buttons on the dash, but a few offer touch controls -- namely, the GPS and "Connected Touch" functionality (in reality, a ridiculously handicapped Android thing they call "Asterisk").

I don't use the GPS very often (my phone is better), and even the apps (esp. TuneIn) I prefer to operate with the physical buttons. So I don't exactly know when this problem started; I only discovered it the other day when I tried to search for a new web radio station within TuneIn. It's not just that app, though, the problem is present in all apps --- **I can no longer operate touch apps, such as on-screen and the virtual keyboard.** This makes the GPS completely unusable, and limits other apps to what's already coded in and accessible via the physical buttons.

Now, question time: **Is there a "hack" or quick way to fix this, or am I looking at a (possibly expensive) repair job?** I've been googling, but haven't turned up any sense that this is a commonly seen or well-known occurrence.

It's been cold recently, I don't know if that's related. I am unhopeful that this problem will "thaw itself away" any time soon.

[image: sample image borrowed from a Google search]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the Internet had no wisdom on this matter, and neither did my mechanic --- but, as it turned out, just moving the car indoors for a while seems to have done the trick.

Comment: ...aaand it got cold again, and it again didn't work. I had expected Volvo to make winter-proof cars, but I'll manage.

Answer (score 2):

Hi I have had exactly the same issue.
It is good to read I am not the only one here. It may have something to do with the cold and the battery. I have learned that when the battery is a little bit to low it will shut down unuseful accessories like the touch screen. This may happen e.g. when you use the stand h eating in the cold days. Nevertheless I have not found any logic behind this as sometimes the cars has not been used for several days and it shows this phenomenen and sometimes no problem at all.